# HtmlInput.focus() not working in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus

I try to code an react app to calculate the typing speed.

I have a problem.

this is some of my code

```
{  txt &&
   txt.map((c, i) => (
      <Character
         key={i}
         value={c}
         id={"id" + i}
         focus={i === 0 ? true : false}
         index={i}
      />
   ))
}
```

where txt is the text script like ["L", "o", "r", "e", "m", ...].

each character in the array render the `<Character />` component.

This is some of `Character.jsx` code:

```
function Character({ value = "-", id, focus, index }) {
    const [char, setChar] = useState("");
    const thisLetter = useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(thisLetter.current.value);

        if (char) {
            // console.log(thisLetter.nextSibling)
            const next = document.querySelector(`.char:nth-child(${index + 1})`)
            next.focus()
        }
    }, [char]);

    return (
        <input
            ref={thisLetter}
            type="text"
            className="border-none p-0 m-0 fs-250 char"
            style={styles}
            value={char}
            onChange={(e) => setChar((v) => e.target.value)}
            maxLength="1"
            placeholder={value}
            id={id}
            autoFocus={focus}
        />
    );
}
```

I am so sorry for taking much of your time in above explaining.

My problem is:
I want to `focus` the next sibling component (input) when the current input filed (length > 0)

I tried

```
thisLetter.current.nextSbling.focus()
```

but it doesn't work.
I also tried

```
const next = document.querySelector(`.char:nth-child(${index + 1})`)
next.focus()
```

But it also doesn't work.

How can I focus the next sibling in javascript?

If you want to see the complete code please check [Github Repo](https://github.com/A7med3bdulBaset/typing-speed)

Comment: Does `thisLetter.current.nextElementSibling.focus()` work?

Comment: No it doesn't work. when i log to the console `thisLetter.current.nextElementSibling` it loges successfully it but the `.focus()` method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem and I will put the solution to whoever wants it.

the problem reason was `autoFocus` attribute, It was `false` always.
look at this old code:
parent component:

```
focus={i === 0 ? true : false}
```

and this in the child component:

```
autoFocus={props.focus}
```

First of all i created state for focus state:

```
const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(props.focus);
```

Then i set autoFocus with the state:

```
autoFocus={isFocus}
```

Then in the validation I made a condition; when the input is validate `setIsFocus(false)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the autoFocus attribute being based on the component prop focus is what’s messing you up.

Comment: i comment the `autoFocus` attribute and it doesn't work also.